# Datatable Editable: Cell Color Resetting after Sorting

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I am trying to have a cell in a Datatable change its background color once it is edited. While [Stéphane's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66949053/change-backgorund-color-of-cell-of-data-table-while-its-value-is-edited-in-rshin) works to an extent, the colors disappear once the table is sorted or filtered. Is there a way to track the edited cell and have it colored as the Datatable is manipulated on the browser end?

Below is the solution as developed by Stéphane and a good reproducible example to start with.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

js <- HTML(
  "function colorizeCell(i, j){
    var selector = '#dtable tr:nth-child(' + i + ') td:nth-child(' + j + ')';
    $(selector).css({'background-color': 'yellow'});
  }"
)

colorizeCell <- function(i, j){
  sprintf("colorizeCell(%d, %d)", i, j)
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  tags$head(
    tags$script(js)
  ),
  br(),
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

dat <- iris[1:5, ]

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE, selection = "none")
  }, server = FALSE)
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    i <- info[["row"]]
    j <- info[["col"]]
    runjs(colorizeCell(i, j+1))
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. When I edit a cell it turns yellow and this color persists after sorting and/or filtering.

Comment: The issue with the colors disappearing changed once I included the ```server=FALSE``` statement in renderDT, and the color persists with the cell regardless of whatever filter I place on it. However, once a filter is applied and the user tries to make further changes, DT will highlight the cell with the original coordinates rather than the intended cell. For example, if cell [3,8] in the filtered DT table was edited, it will highlight cell [3,8] in the unfiltered DT table instead.

Comment: Ah, now I see. Will add an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are coloring the visible row, which need not to correspond with the physical row.

One possible solution is to do the coloring on the **server** side, like this:

```r
library(shiny)
library(DT)
library(dplyr)
library(functional)

dat <- iris[1:5, ]

ui <- fluidPage(
  DTOutput("dtable")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  my_table <- reactiveVal({
    new_dat <- dat %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), list(changed = ~ FALSE)))
    ord <- c(rbind(names(dat), paste0(names(dat), "_changed")))
    new_dat %>% 
      select(all_of(ord))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    targets <- which(grepl("_changed$", names(my_table()))) - 1L
    fns <- lapply(targets, function(ind) 
      function(table) {
        formatStyle(table, ind, ind + 1L,
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(TRUE, "yellow"))
      }) %>% 
      do.call(Compose, .)
    datatable(my_table(), editable = TRUE, selection = "none", rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE,
                                                    targets = targets)))) %>% 
      fns()
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    row <- info$row
    col <- info$col + 1L
    dat <- my_table()
    dat[row, col + 1L] <- TRUE
    dat[row, col] <- info$value
    my_table(dat)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

The idea is to:

1. Add helper columns for each original column wiht the suffix `_changed` (done in the `mutate` call)
2. Create a `reactive` which holds the current data including changes done by the user.
3. In the `renderDT` function you refer to the `reactiveVal` (instead of the static `data.frame`), hide the helper columns and use `formatStyle` to color cells according to the corresponding value in the associated `*_changed` column.
4. The last piece is to keep client and server in sync by adapting your `observeEvent`, where we flag a cell as changed via the corresponding `*_changed` column and also change the value to refelct the changes on the client side.

*N.B.*  Be aware that you R is 1 based while JS is 0 based, hence you need to offset your target index by `-1` (becasue I removed the row names whihc would otherwise be positioned at 0 in JS). This, for whatever strange reason, does not apply for the `formatStyle` function.

[image: Example of a Table where cells are colored according to an edit made]

---

### Update

To keep the filters persistent, you need to store them and to re-apply them:

```r
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  filter_state <- reactiveValues(search = NULL, search_columns = NULL)
  
  format_table <- function(dat) {
    targets <- which(grepl("_changed$", names(dat))) - 1L
    fns <- lapply(targets, function(ind) 
      function(table) {
        formatStyle(table, ind, ind + 1L,
                    backgroundColor = styleEqual(TRUE, "yellow"))
      }) %>% 
      do.call(Compose, .)
    datatable(dat, editable = TRUE, selection = "none", rownames = FALSE,
              options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE,
                                                    targets = targets)))) %>% 
      fns()  
  }
  
  proxy <- dataTableProxy("dtable")
  
  my_table <- reactiveVal({
    new_dat <- dat %>% 
      mutate(across(everything(), list(changed = ~ FALSE)))
    ord <- c(rbind(names(dat), paste0(names(dat), "_changed")))
    new_dat %>% 
      select(all_of(ord))
  })
  
  output[["dtable"]] <- renderDT({
    isolate({
      filter_state$search <- input[["dtable_search"]]
      filter_state$search_columns <- input[["dtable_search_columns"]]
    })
    dat <- my_table()
    format_table(dat)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input[["dtable_cell_edit"]], {
    info <- input[["dtable_cell_edit"]]
    row <- info$row
    col <- info$col + 1L
    dat <- my_table()
    dat[row, col + 1L] <- TRUE
    dat[row, col] <- info$value
    my_table(dat)
  })
  
  observeEvent(c(filter_state$search, filter_state$search_columns), {
    proxy %>% 
      updateSearch(list(global = filter_state$search, 
                        columns = filter_state$search_columns))
  })
  
}
```

The main idea is that upon rendering, we store the search strings - both for the overall search (`dtable_search`) and for potential column specific searches (`dtable_search_columns`). Then all we have to do is to apply the same searches to the `dataTableProxy` object.

Comment: Thank you so much for this solution! Is there a way to keep the filter whenever a change is made? It seems like the filter is automatically removed as the Data Table is regenerated when the change is made.

Comment: Will add an update. WOuld be ncie if you value my answer with an upvote / acceptance.

Comment: Is there a way to keep the edits on the same page after editing? While the overall and column specific searches are kept, it seems as if the DataTable resets to the first page of the results after each edit. It's a problem currently with filtered results that still give me more than the allotted results per page.

Comment: I'm seeing that the updateSearch method doesn't have an argument to take in the page number, so I wonder if this solution may need to be done via JS.